# How to read all .txt files in a folder and append its contents into one .txt file, using Python?

Tags: python, io, listdir

I have a folder with multiple .txt files.
for every .txt file in the folder, I want to take one line of the content and append them in a new .txt file. How to do this in Python?
I'm new to this, also new to publicly asking questions.[this is all I got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mor77.jpg)

```
import os    
Folder = os.listdir('E:\\Project\\tests')   
f = open('outputFile.txt', 'a')   

for file in Folder:   
    file.read()   
    for i in file:   
        f.write(i[1] + '\n')   
f.close()
```

Comment: Please share what have you tried?

Comment: You try it in python and when you have problems you show your code.

Comment: A screenshot has been added. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please copy the code from the screenshot into the question?

Comment: Alright. added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code that you don't open the files to read.

Try this one:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join 

folder_path = 'E:\\Project\\tests'

# get the full names of all the txt files in your folder   
files = [join(folder_path, f) for f in listdir(folder_path) if isfile(join(folder_path, f)) and f.endswith(".txt")] 

f = open('outputFile.txt', 'a')   

for file in files:   
    line = open(file,"r").readlines()[1] # line will be equal to the second line of the file
    f.write(line + '\n')   
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, However, there is one error: NameError: name 'listdir' is not defined. Could you please recheck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Question my bad, try now please